# Как программно вызвать событие клик по карте?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Не отрабатывает метод fire. Мне необходимо вызывать событие клика myMap с моими координатами.
https://pastebin.com/xdqDDW25

Карта встроена в 1С, отображается на форме.
На этой форме есть поля с координатами.
Нужно, чтобы:

1. при открытии формы на карте отображалась точка по этим координатам,
2. чтобы по кнопке в 1С обновлялась метка на карте по координатам (если они изменились например и надо обновить на карте)
   Сейчас,  когда вручную кликаешь на карту: устанавливается точка, в ее "заголовке" адрес, координаты возвращаются в 1С. Т.е. нужно вызвать такое поведение по нужным координатам.

Comment: Это не цель, а средство. Конечную цель опишите. А то может вам проще напрямую открыть балун объекта? В песочнице Яндекса это описано.

Comment: Цель: установить метку/ точку по переданным извне координатам. Чтобы при этом результат был как при интерактивном нажатии. При интерактивном - устанавливается точка, в ее "заголовке" отображается адрес.

Comment: Координаты передаются в мою произвольную функцию. Функция (js) вызывается вообще из 1С, координаты оттуда же.

Comment: Т.е. карта встроена в 1С и нужно поставить метку на этой карте с желаемыми координатами? Или координаты надо вернуть в 1С? Или адрес? Опишите техзадание по-человечески в тексте вопроса – исходное окружение, имеющиеся данные, нужный функционал, текущая проблема. Иначе это одни угадайки получаются, а не адресная помощь.

Comment: Добавил описание. Т.е. мне нужно вызвать поведение со своими координатами как здесь 
 https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode/